# Adding new column in table Crystal Report subreport

Tags: crystal-reports

I generated subreport with wizard. How can I insert new column into the table?[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you're looking to insert a column between the two existing columns (and have your report continue to look nice), it's not trivial in the version of Crystal Reports you're using (based on your screenshot).

You'll have to resize/move your existing fields and field headings to make space (click on them to show resize handles), then drag the new field from the Field Explorer to the details section in the space created.

A newer version of Crystal Reports has added a "Smart Formatting" feature to make column insertion (and related tasks) easier - [this article](http://bi-insider.com/business-intelligence/crystal-reports-2011-crystal-reports-for-enterprise/) contains a summary of the feature.